# PHP 7.1 routing problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4

I'm new in apache2 and php, since few days I'm trying to find a problem what's wrong with my code or server configuration.
When I'm running a simple line such as:

```
$uri = $_REQUEST['URI'];
echo("$uri");
```

I'm receiving an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: URI in /var/www/html/...
```

I need $_REQUEST['URI'] to build my own router.
File .htaccess is added to project, so apache should know that I will override routes. Btw, it looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Of course I ran script from web browser, so the $_REQUEST['URI'] should be defined.
Problem appear on:
PHP 7.1 + Apache2.4 + Ubuntu16.04

Could someone help?

Comment: URI is a querystring variable, right? I.e http://example.com/?URI=something . In any case, i'm almost sure you want to use this as the rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?URI=%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,QSA,L]`

Comment: It doesn't work. The aim is to get proper URL when someone will type in browser i.e example.com/index or example.com/first_subpage, so the $_REQUEST['URI'] should return: example.com/index or example.com/first_subpage depends of what user will type as URL. It is the most simple case of web page routing. Rule which you have rewrite is referring to passing an argument via URL, it is not what I try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file just add this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in your main index.php file just catch the url as

```
<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>
```

So if user open a page like `example.com/test`
 then the output will be `test`

Comment: It doesn't work too, the result is the same as in previous answers given by Eduardo Escobar and Croises. I still receive info: Notice: Undefined index: URI in /var/www/html...

Comment: it should be url not  uri, try `print($_GET);` to see what's coming in the request

Comment: I see the dependency. $_GET parameters were named wrongly. Now it works! Thanks a lot bro :)

Answer (score 0):

As @EduardoEscobar says, what you are trying to do is:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo("$uri");
```